# Setting file name during upload to Cloud Storage

Tags: java, android, google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage, blobstore

I've got an app engine project I use to upload a file from my android device to Google Cloud Storage through the Blobstore API.

```
public class BlobUrlGet extends HttpServlet {


BlobstoreService blServ = BlobstoreServiceFactory.getBlobstoreService();

public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
        throws IOException {


    UploadOptions uploadOptions = UploadOptions.Builder.withGoogleStorageBucketName("abc123-974.appspot.com");
    String blobUploadUrl = blServ.createUploadUrl("/on_upload_success", uploadOptions);




    resp.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);
    resp.setContentType("text/plain");

    PrintWriter out = resp.getWriter();
    out.print(blobUploadUrl);
}

}
```

When I pull up the Cloud Storage console the uploaded files appear with a lengthy name that I'm assuming is simply a Cloud Storage key.

Is there a method in any of the Cloud Storage APIs or Blobstore that allow you to set a file name during the upload? If not how is this typically done?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know any way of customizing a blob name from Blobstore Api, but with Cloud Storage API, you can do as follow :

```
GcsFilename gcsFileName = new GcsFilename(bucketName, fileName)
GcsOutputChannel outputChannel = GcsServiceFactory.createGcsService().createOrReplace(
        gcsFileName,
        new GcsFileOptions.Builder().acl("project-private").build()
        );
OutputStream outputStream = new BufferedOutputStream(Channels.newOutputStream(outputChannel));
```